# Program for length and area of rectangle using functions

Tags: c

I need to write a program that computes the area and perimeter of a rectangle. It must use a function for the area, and a second function for the perimeter.

```c
perimeter = 2 x length + 2 x width = 2l + 2w
area = legnth x width = l x w
```

So far my code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
double perimeter(double x);
double area(double w);
int main (){
    double x, w;
    printf("Enter the length: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    prntf("Enter the width: ");
    scanf("%lf", &w)
    printf("The perimeter is %lf\n", perimeter);
    printf("The area is %lf\n", area);
    return 0;   
}   
double perimeter(double x, w){
    return (2*x)+(2*w);
}
double area(double x, w){
    return (x*w);
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

> (17): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'printf'
>   (17): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%lf" requires an argument of type 'double', but variadic argument 1 has type 'double (___cdecl *)(double)'
>   (18): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%lf" requires an argument of type 'double', but variadic argument 1 has type 'double (___cdecl *)(double)''
>  
>   (21): error C2081: 'w': name in formal parameter list illegal
>   (21): warning C4029: declared formal parameter list different from definition
>   (24): error C2081: 'w': name in formal parameter list illegal 
>   (24): warning C4029: declared formal parameter list different from definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `double perimeter(double x, w)`, write function with arguments like this `double perimeter(double x, double w)`.

Comment: Thank you, that took care of a bunch of the errors.  now I am down to this one: (17) warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%lf' requires and argument of type 'double', but variadic argument 1 has type double (___cdecl *)(double,double)'

Comment: I got it figured out.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues here.

First, your *defined* functions do not match your *declared* functions:

```
//Declared:
double perimeter(double x);
double area(double w);

//Defined:
double perimeter(double x, w){
    return (2*x)+(2*w);
}
double area(double x, w){
    return (x*w);
}
```

In your function declarations you only have one parameter, but in your definition, you try to use two.

Try this:

```
double perimeter(double length, double width){
    return (2*length)+(2*width);
}
double area(double length, double width){
    return (length*width);
}
```

The second problem is when you call your functions:

```
printf("The perimeter is %lf\n", perimeter);
printf("The area is %lf\n", area);
```

You aren't passing the *length* and *width* values to your functions. 
You also missed a semicolon after the second scanf.

Give this a try:

```
int main (){
    double length, width;
    printf("Enter the length: ");
    scanf("%lf", &length);
    prntf("Enter the width: ");
    scanf("%lf", &width);
    printf("The perimeter is %lf\n", perimeter(length, width);
    printf("The area is %lf\n", area(length, width);
    return 0;   
}
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

in the following code is your program running pefectly, the mistake was the way you use your functions, consider the things that the others above wrote you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double perimeter(double x, double w){
    return (2*x)+(2*w);
}
double area(double x, double w){
    return (x*w);
}

int main (){
    double x, w;
    printf("Enter the length: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("Enter the width: ");
    scanf("%lf", &w);
    printf("The perimeter is %lf\n", perimeter(x,w));
    printf("The area is %lf\n", area(x,w));
    return 0;
}
```

Check this code with yours and find your errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code are

The declarations and definitions do not match. The correct declaration would be
`double perimeter(double w, double x)` and `double area(double w,double x)`.

**NOTE:** Always remember that the order, type and number of arguments must match while declaring, defining and calling the corresponding function.

When you are calling functions `perimeter` and `area` in printf, you are not passing arguments. As you will see in your declaration and definition of functions you have used `perimeter(double x,w)` and `area(double x,w)`.

So the correct lines would be

```
 printf("The perimeter is %lf\n", perimeter(x,w));
 printf("The area is %lf\n", area(x,w));
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, it seems that you have much more mistakes, so I correct them all and post a new answer with full corrected code, you can compare it with yours.

```
#include <stdio.h>
double perimeter(double x, double w);
double area(double x, double w);
int main (){
    double x, w;
    printf("Enter the length: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("Enter the width: ");
    scanf("%lf", &w);
    printf("The perimeter is %lf\n", perimeter(x, w));
    printf("The area is %lf\n", area(x, w));
    return 0;
}
double perimeter(double x, double w){
    return (2*x)+(2*w);
}
double area(double x, double w){
    return (x*w);
}
```